# how to disable weak cipher TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA in Apache Traffic Server version 4.1

Tags: apache, rc4-cipher

I am trying to disable weak cipher TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA in Apache Traffic Server version 4.1 reported by nap scan

I have RC4 removed in the SSLCipherSuite

```
cat records.config | grep RC4
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.server.cipher_suite STRING !RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-SHA:ALL:!aNULL:!EXP:!LOW:!MD5:!SSLV2:!NULL
```

!RC disabled 2 other suites protocols TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5  and TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA , But TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA  is stil active.  As RC4 cipher suites are weak I want to disable it. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

cipher TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA

Disable with:
SSLCipherSuite !EECDH+aRSA+RC4